# Speeding the Android edit-debug cycle

Tags: android

Developing applications for Android in Eclipse, press F11 to run the program in the emulator.

However, this means waiting for the emulator to bootup (and then unlocking the emulator's screen) each time you want to test changes to your program.  Is there any way around this delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OJW

Are you closing the emulator after you test the app?

If you leave it running and then start your application from Eclipse again it will re-deploy and start (and avoid the overhead of starting the emulator).

You can also stop the application from the emulator perspective in eclipse before re-starting it.

-- Frank

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Frank.  I tried it in Android Studio and it works there too.  My emulator is up and running my app, and Studio is not running it (it didn't run it, but only packaged and deployed it).  I can change code and Select Run|Run'app' from the menu and within about 30 seconds, the emulator is running the new code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a physical device, you can use it instead of the emulator, it's much faster.

Comment: OK, let's examine this option.  I have a physical device. I've just changed a line of code and I'd like to test it.  Android tools - export signed application package.  Enter 2 passwords in 4 dialogs.  Get an ipk. Upload it to my website. Download it in phone's browser. Go to notification area, select the recent download, open package manager and install it.  Open it. Run it.  Now running my new software. It only took 17 steps.

Comment: @OJW: if you have your device plugged in via USB and have the USB driver installed, pressing F11 from Eclipse will launch it on your device, not the emulator. You can even have both the emulator and your device on, and on launch Eclipse will ask you which to use.